# Input.GetAxis for android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a maze game and curently i am having delays with my android  controls. I have lade the computer controls to move front and to turn left and right and to jump using input.getaxis. Now on android i created buttons that work but not how i want. It can jump and turn how i want but it doesnt move properly. There are 2 problems one is that when i click it moves a bit and then i need to click again but i want to hold and it will move continuously and second problem is that when i turn the character doesnt move the corect way it goes always on x axis with input.getaxis everything works perfectly but i need something that will work for androdid like that, here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    public float speedj;
    Rigidbody rb;
    static Animator anim;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    public void Walk ()
    {
        anim.SetTrigger ("Walk");
        rb.velocity = new Vector3 (0,0,7f);
    }
    public void Left ()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0,-90f,0);
    }
    public void Right ()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0,90f,0);
    }
    public void Jump ()
    {
        anim.SetTrigger ("Jump");
        rb.velocity = new Vector3 (0,4f,0);

    }
    public void StopVelocity ()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        transform.Translate(0,0,0);
    }
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        float z = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        transform.Translate (0,0,z);
        transform.Rotate (0,x,0);
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger ("Jump");
            rb.velocity = new Vector3 (0,speedj,0);
        }
    }
}
```

So this is it the fixedUpdate functionis for the computer the others are for buttons for android i am using event trigger for pointer up and down events pleasehelp me to change the code so that it will work for android like it works with Input.getAxis for computer thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "when i click it moves a bit and then i need to click again but i want to hold and it will move continuously."

Using the [EventTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html) here should be the optimal way. Check out OnPointerDown(); the function should be called for every frame. You should attach the EventTrigger to the button for it to work on mobiles.

> "when i turn the character doesnt move the corect way."

Try moving using your Local Transforms Forward. Namely [Transform.Forward()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html). It will allow you to move forward into the direction you set before, the Forward is always a Normalized Vector3. Moving in the way you are will use the world axis, your rotation wont matter at all.

Comment: i used eventtrigger already thanks i will try and let you know i think with the rotation it will work but with event trigger i tried alread with pointer thanks maybe you have other solution for the first problem

Comment: I also used oppointerup maybe  i should delete it maybe it is bad